# Flutter failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug' key is missing in map

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I run `flutter doctor -v` everything seems to be just fine. But when I run my app used android studio I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> Key /home/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/app_frontend/build/app/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/142.jar is missing in the map.
>
> at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapWithDefaultKt.getOrImplicitDefaultNullable(MapWithDefault.kt:24)
>
> at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.getValue(Maps.kt:341)

I can't find any related information about `FirebasePerformancePlugin key is missing error` and I don't know even how to start investigate that error.

Hope for help, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why I got that error on a first place (All I know is that I run `flutter build apk --release` before I got this error, but I'm not sure if it is related).

`flutter clean` solved my issue.

Comment: This doesn't solve mine. Anyone else has another suggestion?